# Raspberry Pi 7 Inch Touchscreen Brightness Control - How to avoid write operation to SD card

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, sd-card, touchscreen, brightness

I'm just creating an app(kivy) for a raspberry pi(3b) with 7 inch touchdisplay. In addition I implemented a light sensor (TSL2591), which can regulate the brightness of the backlight using following command:

```
os.system('sudo sh -c "echo '+str(brightness)+' > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness"')
```

with values of brightness 0 to 255

Works fine so far, but I do update the brightness once a second. If I'm not wrong, the command overwrites a config file and I mind of write access to the SD Card that often. I think the SD card will be corrupt after a short period of time.

For sure I can try to get less write operations, but it also leads to less smoothness:

- update slower than 1 sec
- only write if brightness value really changes
- don't use all of the 255 steps

So the main question is: is there any other way to control the brightness? Or any workaround? I could not find a "real" Datasheet or any other advice on the internet. So maybe there is another way.

Comment: That's not a convential disk file; it's a device special file which the kernel artificially creates to look like a disk file. You need not worry.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for making me understand whats going on. I wasn't aware of such files, working as an interface to a device driver. needed the right keyword to google it. This helped me understand also: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file).

Comment: I've put it as an answer to *"solve"* the question and so that other folks can see it easily without scrabbling around in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a conventional disk file; it's a *"device special file"* which the kernel artificially creates to look like a disk file. It allows you to *"talk"* to device drivers using standard `read()` and `write()` calls.

You need not worry about SD card wear.